# How can I thoroughly test all the hardware on my computer?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, battery

Here's what would be ideal:

1. A list of all the hardware components potentially found on one's computer
2. A method (or list of methods) for testing each of these
3. The accuracy of these methods

My personal requests are:

```
-How to test your motherboard
-How to test your wireless receiving apparatus
-How to test CD/DVD-RW drive
-How to test your laptop battery
-How to test your Heat sink(s)?
-How to test the effectiveness of your fan(s)
```

Favorite answers: OS-independent tests which GUARANTEE the concerned hardware works PERFECTLY

Comment: No test can ever guarantee that anything works PERFECTLY...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No test suite can *guarantee* that anything works *perfectly*, they can only tell you if the computer passed the tests.

This Live-CD does some of it, I have never seen anyone test the CD/DVD or wifi. But any live-cd meant for ordinary use should allow you to test that manually.

[StressLinux](http://www.stresslinux.org/sl/)

> StressLinux is a minimal linux
>   distribution running from a bootable
>   cdrom (LiveCD) or via PXE. Stresslinux
>   is dedicated to users who want to test
>   their system(s) entirely on high load
>   and monitoring the health.
>
> Features:
>
> - stress 0.18.1 (A tool to impose certain types of stress on a POSIX
>     system.)
> - CPUBurn 1.4 (CPU maximum load (heat) stability test)
> - CPU Burn-In 1.00 (CPU burn-in test)
> - nbench 2.2.1 (CPU test suite)
> - iometer 2003.12.16 (I/O performance meter)
> - hddtemp 0.3beta11 (A program to display the temperature of your hard
>     drive.)
> - lm_sensors 2.8.7 (LM78 and other hardware monitor drivers.)
> - busybox 1.0.0rc3 (Single small executable which contains common UNIX
>     utilities)
> - lshw A.01.07 (Hardware lister)
> - **bonnie++ 1.03a (Hard drive benchmark)**
> - netio 1.23 (Network benchmark)
> - smartmontools 5.32 (S.M.A.R.T. drivetests)
> - x86info 1.12b (CPU information)
> - memtest86 3.1a (A stand-alone memory diagnostic)
> - memtest86+ 1.15 (An other stand-alone memory diagnostic)

Comment: actual homepage: http://www.stresslinux.org/sl/

Comment: @scott - updated url

Comment: @Nifle Are there any risks to the hardware associated with using stresslinux? For example, could pushing my CPU to the limit possibly break the CPU or melt any surrounding part?

Comment: @Shawn - No. What it can (in theory) do is push any partly defective part far enough so that it fails completely. It can't destroy or harm a functioning computer.

Comment: @Nifle So if I suspect some parts of being defective, should I run the tests?

Comment: @Shawn - That's what I'd do. What tests and for how long is up to you. I have only done a few hours test but If I was to sell the computer I'd probably do a more thorough test, perhaps run it over night or so.

Comment: @Nifle - Is there a way to tell it to simply "run as many tests as possible and tell me about the results in the morning"?

Comment: @Shawn - I have *No* idea. I have not done stuff like this for oh.... more than five years. Just download the iso, burn it and play around with it. It's not going to break anything.

Answer (score 2):

If money is no object [the PC Doctor testing suite](http://www.pcdservicecenter.com/) is pretty damned good.  It's pretty damned expensive though...

Comment: If I had that much money, I would buy a new computer :D

Comment: @Shawn - No debate there. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Or a very easy way: go to a computer store and pay a small sum, and they will do this test for you. If all else fails, download a simple tuning program which can typically give the computer a test.

If you have a HP computer they normally have a POST test and some diagnostic tools built-in to them, telling you if something fails. AKA the S.M.A.R.T test for hard drives.

Comment: POST and SMART are completely different things. The first is run only once at each startups (and takes seconds), the other is a monitoring performed during the whole lifetime of the HDD.